# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' when iterating over columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Python. I'm trying to automate dummy conversion for categorical data using pandas. This is my code:

```
class TransformData(object):

    def __init__(self,dataframe):
        self.df = dataframe

    def convert_to_dummies_and_drop_join(self,series):
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df,pd.get_dummies(series,drop_first=True),self.df.drop([series.name],axis=1)],axis=1)
        return self.df
    
    def get_final_dataframe(self):
        column_list = self.df.columns.tolist()
        for column in column_list:
            print(column)
            print(self.df[column].dtype)
            if(self.df[column].dtype == np.dtype('O')):
                self.convert_to_dummies_and_drop_join(self.df[column])
            else:
                pass
        return self.df
```

After that I try to instantiate and run:

```
 td = TransformData(train)
 td.get_final_dataframe()
```

I get few columns right:

```
ID
int64
y
float64
X0
object
X1
```

Then on the next column it throws this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-62ca453884a3> in <module>
----> 1 td.get_final_dataframe()

<ipython-input-90-a7c3848114f7> in get_final_dataframe(self)
     14         for column in column_list:
     15             print(column)
---> 16             print(self.df[column].dtype)
     17             if(self.df[column].dtype == np.dtype('O')):
     18                 self.convert_to_dummies_and_drop_join(self.df[column])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I'm unable to figure out why it's saying it is DataFrame attribute when in fact I'm applying dtype to a series. If I simply print the column dtypes without calling `convert_to_dummies_and_drop_join`, it outputs all the dtypes correctly. So the problem is most likely in that code.

Comment: it is because once you enter in the if statement, then the function `convert_to_dummies_and_drop_join` create duplicated columns (you concat `self.df` and `self.df.drop([series.name],axis=1)`). So for you, because the col X0 is object, at the next loop, there is at least 2 columns X1 due to the concat

Comment: so if you remove `self.df` in the concat, then it should work, EXCEPT if one of the dummies columns created has the same name than one of your original columns.

Comment: I came very close. I was wondering about duplicate column names and was on my way to check if pandas sort of aggregates two series into a dataframe if columns have the same name, called this way. Thanks it works now.